# Double underline tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to make some text double-underlined in HTML.

```html
<h1><u><i> website </i></u></h1>
```

I have two lines on the bottom instead of one. Is there a certain tag for that or would I have to do it in css?

Comment: http://voices.yahoo.com/double-underline-other-html-tricks-1297339.html

Comment: @Jeff I haven't really tried anything but I've looked it up but didn't find anything.

Comment: @11684 I don't know JS or any hacking of any kind.

Comment: Well, 'hack' in 'a JS hack' isn't related to 'hacking a computer' or something like that. What I meant with a 'JS hack' is a piece of JavaScript that solves this problem with some functions that are not designed to solve this problem (so, just abuses a function). @Kevril

Comment: Oh, and don't use `<u>`. It's deprecated. Use CSS for underlining instead.

Comment: @11684 well i don't know JS so ya

Comment: Learn JS! It's fun! @Kevril

Comment: @11684 once i know how to make a double underline thing

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can try to add this:

```
h1.dblUnderlined { border-bottom: 3px double; }
```

*Note: The width must be `3px` or greater because it represents the total width; not the width of each border. As you increase the measurement, the width of the lines and space may or may not be equal based on the divisibility of the defined measurement by 3. A remainder of 1, and 1 is added to the width of the space; a remainder of 2 will result in 1 being added to each line.*

Answer (score 25):

Use a border **and** and underline:

```
.doubleUnderline {
    text-decoration:underline;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

<span class="doubleUnderline">Test</span>
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLMcZ/1/).

Comment: From prior experience: make sure the element you apply this class to is `display: inline` or acts accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/SLMcZ/1/

Comment: I got this to work but the lines are farther apart then I would like them to be, it's not a big problem, so is there a way to make the be closer?

Comment: Decrease the height of the span (blind guess). @Kevril

Comment: I have found that this method yields lines that don't always align properly in some situations (such as if other type styles are applied to the text). So, I prefer the `double` border method.

Answer (score 7):

guys/gals, this works as well but is more like a traditional double underline.

```
.doubleUnderline {
     text-decoration-line: underline;
     text-decoration-style: double;
}
```

Comment: Dpo note that this works very poorly with any characters that are below the line like commas, the letter j....etc As the underlie vanishes on that spot

Comment: Yes this is unfortunate, yet it is more of a traditional method then a bottom border.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to set a bottom border of type `double` in CSS. It needs to be at least 3 pixels wide to create the minimal double border (two 1px borders with 1px spacing between them).

The details depend on the markup, on the desired width and color of the double line, and whether it should run across the available width. Markup like `<h1><u><i> website </i></u></h1>` is probably not meant to be serious. With the simple markup `<h1>foobar</h1>`, a way to get a minimal double border across the page is to use

```
h1 {
  border-bottom: double 3px;
}
```

If you want to have just the heading text “underlined”, the simplest way is to have inner markup, like `<h1><span>foobar</span></h1>`, and CSS code

```
h1 span {
  border-bottom: double 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I need it everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, at the moment, the following is possible in Firefox, or in Safari using a vendor prefix:

```
text-decoration: underline double;
-webkit-text-decoration: underline double;
```

See [text-decoration-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make your own "tag"?

```
<style>
du
{
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-style: double;
}
</style>
<p> I want <du>this stuff</du> double underlined.</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eoba541g/2/

Answer (score 0):

#### use the following http://jsfiddle.net/cKNP4/

#### or

Give the following **style** to any HTML container:
`border-top-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-bottom-style:double;border-left-style:none;border-width: 2px solid black;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (stylus):

```stylus
$borderWidth 1px
$textColour black

$double-borders
    &:after
        content ""
        position absolute
        top 100%
        width 5.7em
        right 0
        border-top ($borderWidth * 3) double $textColour

.double-underlined
    @extend $double-borders
```

Note that the width must be hard-coded (in this case `5.7em`.  If this isn't the desired result, you can also use the `border-bottom` technique mentioned above.

Comment: What language/markup is this? It's neither HTML nor CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 style="text-decoration: underline double;"><u>About Us</u></h1>
```

This would work, only if you want to double underline it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration: double underline;`

Enter the code in your style tag.

It will then double underline your text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).